# Java two dimensional tables

Tags: java

I need to make a two dimensional table that has two columns with the following code.

```
public static void printCommonLogTable() {
double x = 0.0;
int i = 1;
while (x <= 10.0) {
System.out.print(x + "   " + Math.log(x) + "   ");
x = x + 0.5; }
System.out.println("");
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    printCommonLogTable();
}
```

The first column in the table should be the number for which you are computing the log and the second column should be the result.

But when I run this, everything is on the same line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because your call to `System.out.println("");` is misplaced: it should be at the end of the `while` loop (but *inside* it). This is easier to see when the code is correctly indented, like this:

```
public static void printCommonLogTable() {
    double x = 0.0;
    while (x <= 10.0) {
        System.out.print(x + "   " + Math.log(x) + "   ");
        x = x + 0.5;
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Note that I removed the unused `i` variable, and replaced `System.out.println("");` with just `System.out.println();`

You can also combine the two print statements in one:

```
public static void printCommonLogTable() {
    double x = 0.0;
    while (x <= 10.0) {
        System.out.println(x + "   " + Math.log(x) + "   ");
        x = x + 0.5;
    }
}
```

Comment: Also, `System.out.println();` can be removed, and the previous `System.out.print` can be replaced with `System.out.println`

Comment: @BackSlash I was just writing that yes :)

Comment: @SikkiNixx Feel free to upvote / accept this answer if it helped you.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
  double x = 0.0;
  int i = 1;
  while (x <= 10.0) {
    System.out.println(x + "   " + Math.log(x) + "   ");  // old : System.out.print(x + "   " + Math.log(x) + "   ");
    x = x + 0.5; }

}
```

The println("...") method prints the string "..." and moves the cursor to a new line. The print("...") method instead prints just the string "...", but does not move the cursor to a new line. Hence, subsequent printing instructions will print on the same line. The println() method can also be used without parameters, to position the cursor on the next line.